# how to identify keys in dictionary-python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

Hi i need to get my program to display only the values that appear as keys and never as values in a dictionary?

i tried and got the values and keys stored in a dictionary and now i don't know how to identify the one that is only a key and never a value

lets say i have `dict[('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '4'), ('3', '4'), ('5', '6')]`

now the only item that only appears as a key and not a value is 1 and 5 so how do i get my program to display

only a key not a value:

```
    1
    5
```

Comment: `dict[(   )]` would be syntax error, if you don't over writes dict (that is misuse) Any ways this is not a dictionary.

Comment: I'm charitably assuming he means `dict([('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '4'), ('3', '4'), ('5', '6')])`

Comment: i have changed it so the dictionary has no error but another question, how would i change it so it displays the entire dictionary that i have inside a function and than afterwards display the keys that are never values.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
set(d.keys()) - set(d.values())
```

Note that your example has a problem (apart from the syntax mistake).  You have two tuples with `'1'` as the first element.  A dict can't have the same key twice.  The second one will override the first, so `('1', '2')` will not make it into the dict, and so '2' is also a key that does not occur as a value.

Comment: OP not using dict.. and `(d.values()` is syntax error

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: What do you mean "not using dict"?

Comment: i have changed it so the dictionary has no error but another question, how would i change it so it displays the entire dictionary that i have inside a function and than afterwards display the keys that are never values.

Comment: @user3467226: I don't really understand your question.  You can print the dictionary any time you like.

Comment: yes but i have it inside a function and i need to separate the things that only appear as keys outside the function and since the dict is inside a function and the separation happens outside it doesn't work because it not a global variable

Comment: @user3467226: It sounds like you have a separate question there that you should ask separately.

Comment: ok and the code u have given how do i display it? print(what?)

Comment: @user3467226: `print` just what I showed: `print set(d.keys()) - set(d.values())`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not iterate through the `dict` as follows:

```
allowed = [i for i in my_dict if i not in my_dict.values()]
```